# Why is always an ActionResult as return type defined although a ViewResult or PartialViewResult is returned

Tags: asp.net-mvc

2 typical samples:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
   return PartialView();
}
```

Why do they not return the most appropriate type like ViewResult and PartialViewResult?

Comment: Because you have to redundantly change the declared return type when you change the actual return type (or introduce a second one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course they can have a `ViewResult` or `PartialViewResult` return type *in this case*. But what benefit exactly would it give to you? What if later you decide that in some case (e.g. when the request comes from an Ajax call) you want to return `JsonResult`?

You typically do not handle the return value of an action method yourself. It's processed behind the scenes by the MVC framework, so you really don't care about the signature.

Comment: Ok fine what you say is what I just thought that I can independently change the concrete return value without changing the action signature. Even for unit tests it does not matter if I check for the IsInstanceOfType(...) It tests always the conrete one I really expect. Btw. you should not eat the flower :P

Comment: BUT... why has the Remote Validaton action always a JsonResult return type? Thats then the only exception I know.

Comment: @Elisa I am not familiar with Remove Validation but after skimming through the basics, it seems as some kind of contract, including also the format of the data passed from the action method (requiring JSON). From some of the samples I have found, it seems that `ActionResult` return type in the signature should be fine, though.

Comment: Yes ActionResult is fine instead of the json stuff the action still works but I just wondered why msdn shows a JsonResult... maybe the trainee did that article...