# unit testing of very small asp.net mvc actions returning json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, action

The first line of my action is tested with an extra integration test.
The second line is tested with an extra unit test for automapper mapping stuff
The third line is untested then.

The below unit test does it test the third line? because it just tests the return type.

This seems stupid or too trivial too me. What else should the method return????

There is no if/else logic inside this action. Therefore just testing for type == JsonNetResult seems superfluid for me. I would not even realize in my unit test if someone removes the success = true anonymous type.

Should I rather test the data of the JsonNetResult with QUnit?

I would be glad about some guidance and tips because the actions returning Json data drive me crazy... Its just fetch data from db and put it inside the JsonNetResult object.

**Action**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetTemplateRootUnits(int templateId)
{
    IEnumerable<Unit> units = _dataProvider.GetTemplateRootUnits(templateId);
    IEnumerable<UnitTreeViewModel> unitTreeViewModels = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Unit>, IEnumerable<UnitTreeViewModel>>(units);
    return new JsonNetResult(new { data = unitTreeViewModels, success = true });
}
```

**Unit test**

```
[Test]
public void GetTemplateRootUnits_TemplateExists_ReturnsJsonNetResult()
{
    // ARRANGE  
    Mock<IUnitDataProvider> mock1 = new Mock<IUnitDataProvider>();
    Mock<IMappingEngine> mock2 = new Mock<IMappingEngine>();
    Mock<ControllerContext> mock3 = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
    UnitController controller = new UnitController(mock1.Object, mock2.Object);
    mock1.Setup(m => m.GetTemplateRootUnits(1)).Returns(new List<Unit> 
    { 
        new Unit{ UnitId = 1, Name = "Name1", HasChildren = false},
        new Unit{ UnitId = 2, Name = "Name2", HasChildren = false},
        new Unit{ UnitId = 3, Name = "Name3", HasChildren = false},
    });

    var unitTreeViewModels = new List<UnitTreeViewModel> 
    { 
        new UnitTreeViewModel { Id = 1, Name = "Name1", HasChildren = false},
        new UnitTreeViewModel { Id = 2, Name = "Name2", HasChildren = false},
        new UnitTreeViewModel { Id = 3, Name = "Name3", HasChildren = false},
    };

    // Thats the way AutoMapper is mocked
    mock2.Setup(m => m.Map<IEnumerable<Unit>, IEnumerable<UnitTreeViewModel>>(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Unit>>())).Returns(unitTreeViewModels);

    // ACT
    ActionResult result = controller.GetTemplateRootUnits(1);

    // ASSERT - check that the dataProvider.GetTestplanRootUnits() was called
    mock1.Verify(m => m.GetTemplateRootUnits(1));

    // ASSERT
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(JsonNetResult), result);
}
```

**JsonNetResult.cs**

```
public class JsonNetResult : ContentResult
    {
        private readonly object _data;
        public JsonNetResult(object data)
        {
            _data = data;
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data);
            ContentType = "application/json";
            base.ExecuteResult(context);
        }
        public object Data { get { return _data; } }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown what the `JsonNetResult` class is, but I will assume that it is some custom action result using JSON.NET as serializer instead of the default JavaScriptSerializer. I will also assume that this class exposes a public property of type object called `Data` holding the model that is to be serialized:

```
public class JsonNetResult: ActionResult
{
    public JsonNetResult(object data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
    public object Data { get; private set; }

    ...
}
```

So you could test the data inside the result:

```
// ASSERT
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(JsonNetResult), result);

var jsonResult = result as JsonNetResult;
var data = new RouteValueDictionary(jsonResult.Data);
Assert.IsTrue((bool)data["success"]);
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(data["data"], typeof(IEnumerable<UnitTreeViewModel>));
Assert.AreEqual(unitTreeViewModels, data["data"]);
```

Comment: Thanks Darin that you take time. Its always a pleasure to learn from you! I have posted my JsonNetResult class see init question. What I do not undestand here is why you use the RouteValueDictionary? You could also cast the jsonResult.Data to (IEnumerable<UnitTreeViewModel>) in the unit test and it would work the same way and get the same results. Please explain the difference in your opinion. One thing is sure. When I call the controller.action the ExecuteResult is not called naturally. Therefore your code is not a real json test imho.

Comment: @Elisa, I am using `RouteValueDictionary` in order to be able to access the properties of the anonymous object that you passed to the `JsonNetResult` constructor inside the unit test. And **no**, you cannot cast `jsonResult.Data` to `IEnumerable<UnitTreeViewModel>` because `jsonResult.Data` represents an anonymous object which is the reason I use `RouteValueDictionary`. This anonymous object has 2 properties: `data` and `success`.

Comment: Arghhh... I stepped into the compile time object trap. It compiles but does not run hehe. Ok your point. When I test my JsonNetResult now as you recommended, what would be the next way of towards testing the user interface? Should I go for QUnit and test my getJson functions or should I directly go for Selenium browser tests? You already has the solution. Thanks Darin.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to test type of return value. You need to set type of return value in signature of method.

```
public JsonNetResult GetTemplateRootUnits(int templateId);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921382/why-is-always-an-actionresult-as-return-type-defined-although-a-viewresult-or-pa and even I would set it to JsonNetResult, what should I test in that action? There is only the third line and the return type is always the same...

Comment: Signature of public method is public contract. You cannot simple change it and you don't need to test it. There is no to _unit_ test in your method, cause it is not do any work. You can write integration test for it, but it will be something like this: we get special testing template from db and check that return value is same as predefined value.

Comment: Why Do you mention that a public method is a public contract? I have never doubted that anywhere!

Comment: I say about it with mention that you don't need to test your public contract